# Adding a hook based on user's shipping state after checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, checkout

I am seeking advice on how to utilize WooCommerce hooks in conjunction with my order status after a user checks out. I have created a custom order status and would like the order to automatically go to that status based on the user's shipping state that the user enters during checkout.

For example: User is from PA -> order status automatically sets to 'East Coast'

The code below is the one I have used for creating a new order status

```
/** 
 * Register East Coast status
**/
function register_processing_newtown_square_status() {
register_post_status( 'wc-processing-ec', array(
    'label'                     => 'Processing East Coast',
    'public'                    => true,
    'exclude_from_search'       => false,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Processing East Coast <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Processing East Coast <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_processing_east_coast_status' );

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_register_processing_east_coast_status( $order_statuses ) {

$new_order_statuses = array();

// add new order status after processing
foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {

    $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;

    if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
        $new_order_statuses['wc-processing-ec'] = 'Processing East Coast';
    }
}

return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_register_processing_east_coast_status' );
```

Can anyone give me any insight on using a WooCommerce hook to grab the user's state information in the cart and have it linked to this order status when they checkout?

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/

Comment: http://chrislema.com/automating-woocommerce-order-status-changes/

I'm trying to follow this tutorial and use:

`add_filter (‘woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status’, ‘change_processing_east_coast’);`

but am ultimately lost on adding the correct hook from the user's input from checkout and force changing the status.

Comment: `if ( isset( $this->posted['billing_state'] ) ) {
    WC()->customer->set_state( $this->posted['billing_state'] );
   }`

I believe I must utilize this piece which is where WooCommerce checks the user input to spit out the shipping price, found in /includes/class-wc-checkout.php